# How to extract filename.tar.gz file

Tags: linux, file, gzip, tar

I want to extract an archive named `filename.tar.gz`.

Using `tar -xzvf filename.tar.gz` doesn't extract the file. it is gives this error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Comment: `file filename.tar.gz` "file" will show you the format (if installed), if its a zip, try `unzip` or install a generic unpacker, like `unp`.

Comment: The error means that the file is not a `gzip` file, although the extension says so. Try `unzip filename.tar.gz` and `gunzip filename.tar.gz` and see what the output is.

Comment: From where did you get that zip file?

Comment: This file is system generated file from crontab.

Comment: @Max Leske thanks for you suggestion but when i tried `gunzip filename.tar.gz` it gives error message : `not in gzip format`

Comment: @pce `file filename.tar.gz` gives this message: POSIX tar archive

Comment: This really should be on alt.se.unix, not here.

Comment: I had the same issue. It was wget issue where it didn't download the entire tar.gz file. I was able to resolved it by FTPing the file directly to Linux box.

Comment: Sometimes this issue happens when the downloaded tarball file is not proper.

Comment: it says HTML with very long text

Answer (score 194, accepted):

If `file filename.tar.gz` gives this message: POSIX tar archive, 
the archive is a tar, not a GZip archive.

Unpack a tar without the `z`, it is for gzipped (compressed), only:

```
mv filename.tar.gz filename.tar # optional
tar xvf filename.tar
```

Or try a generic Unpacker like `unp` (https://packages.qa.debian.org/u/unp.html), a script for unpacking a wide variety of archive formats.

determine the file type:

```
$ file ~/Downloads/filename.tbz2
/User/Name/Downloads/filename.tbz2: bzip2 compressed data, block size = 400k
```

Comment: Thanks @pce for your support. your answer is correct. `tar xvf filename.tar.gz`. It works for me.

Comment: tar xvf hadoop-2.7.2.tar
tar: Ceci ne ressemble pas à une archive de type « tar »
tar: Arrêt avec code d'échec à cause des erreurs précédentes

Answer (score 17):

As far as I can tell, the command is correct, ASSUMING your input file is a valid gzipped tar file. Your output says that it isn't. If you downloaded the file from the internet, you probably didn't get the entire file, try again.

Without more knowledge of the source of your file, nobody here is going to be able to give you a concrete solution, just educated guesses.

Comment: This made me take a second look at the file I was downloading. It was from apache and the url ends in .tar.gz so I just copy and pasted it. However, that link wasn't for the tarball, it was for a page listing mirrors for the tarball. So for 30 minutes I was trying to untar an html page. Wtf apache.

Comment: I had this issue,  double check that your file is the correct size,  also use a checksum if possible.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same error 
the result of command :

```
file hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz
```

is `hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz: HTML document, ASCII text`

the reason that the file is not gzip format due to problem in download or other.

Comment: did you manage to sort this out? Having same issue here.

Comment: @arilwan If you're having an issue with this, try opening the file in a text editor. The answer is saying that there was a download error, so they got an HTML error page INSTEAD of the expected gzip file. The download program (wget?) still saved it with the .gz extension.

Answer (score 5):

It happens sometimes for the files downloaded with "wget" command. Just 10 minutes ago, I was trying to install something to server from the command screen and the same thing happened. As a solution, I just downloaded the .tar.gz file to my machine from the web then uploaded it to the server via FTP. After that, the "tar" command worked as it was expected.

Comment: hmm, check the wget log, maybe you were getting redirected or something

Answer (score 2):

Internally `tar xcvf <filename>` will call the binary `gzip` from the `PATH` environment variable to decompress the files in the `tar` archive. Sometimes third party tools use a custom `gzip` binary which is not compatible with the `tar` binary.
It is a good idea to check the `gzip` binary in your `PATH` with `which gzip` and make sure that a correct `gzip` binary is called.

Answer (score 0):

A tar.gz is a tar file inside a gzip file, so 1st you must unzip the gzip file with `gunzip -d filename.tar.gz` , and then use `tar` to untar it. However, since `gunzip` says it isn't in gzip format, you can see what format it is in with `file filename.tar.gz`, and use the appropriate program to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the file is complete.  This error message can occur if you only partially downloaded a file or if it has major issues.  Check the MD5sum.

Answer (score 0):

The other scenario you mush verify is that the file you're trying to unpack is not empty and is valid.

In my case I wasn't downloading the file correctly, after double check and I made sure I had the right file I could unpack it without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically the seemingly `tar.gz` file is not really in the format it should be. This can be ascertained using `file` Linux command. Example, for a genuine `.tgz` file, the command output will be as below:

```
root@f562353fc1ab:/app# file kafka_2.13-2.8.0.tgz 
kafka_2.13-2.8.0.tgz: gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT), original size modulo 2^32 75202560
```

So, the source from where you received the file hasn't sent it in the correct format. If you have downloaded the supposedly `.tgz` file from a URI, may be the URI is wrong. In my case, I faced the same issue while extracting kafka binary (`.tgz` file). Turns out, that the URI to `wget` was incorrect. At least for kafka, to get the correct download link, from the downloads page (https://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html) , we must traverse to the page that is highlighted by the link representing the binary. Once we are in that page, we will get the exact link to download the binary. Also, during download, `wget` displays the type of the file that will be downloaded.  It will print something like this to indicate the type.

`Length: unspecified [text/html]` --> Incorrect URI.

`Length: 71403603 (68M) [application/octet-stream]` --> Correct URI.