# Php download file corruption

Tags: php

I am trying to download a .tgz file using the following:

```
$file = '/var/www/upload/myfile.tgz';

if (file_exists($file))
{
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

The problem is that  when I 'm trying to extract the downloaded file
 with `tar` gives me the following error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

note: this error does not occur when trying to extract the original file.

Comment: the archive is a tar, not a GZip archive.

Comment: Unpack a tar without the z, it is for gzipped (compressed), only:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744023/how-to-extract-filename-tar-gz-file

Comment: @JunaidAhmed , @saty Im using  `tar xf myfile.tgz ` which is working for the original but not for the downloaded

Comment: check the exact filesize of the two, or do a compare of the files if you have the tools

Comment: Are you sure that you don't output anything else before the readfile? (you can disable output buffering and see if php shows errors)

Comment: @Thomas I 'm not sure how to disable output buffering, I tried with an htaccess but didn't work

Comment: You can add ```ob_end_flush()``` and the beginning of the download script. If you see errors that you can not add header information it should show you where you already started to output something ahead of the download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I moved the code to a separate .php file

Comment: Than it seems that in your old php file you echoed some chars, e.g. Whitespaces at the beginning or so in front of your headers and exit calls.