# Not able to install IE in centos 7

Tags: internet-explorer, centos7

**Commands which I used for installing**
1)yum install epel-release
2)yum install wine 
3)wget http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/downloads/ies4linux-latest.tar.gz
Till these steps I dont have any issue.

4)tar -xf ies4linux-latest.tar.gz
When I use this command tar -xf ies4linux-latest.tar.gz
I get the following error.
**gzip: stdin: not in gzip format                                                                                         tar: Child returned status 1                                                                                            tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now**

I am stuck here.
Please suggest how I should resolve this error and install IE in my Centos machine.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, the file is not a gzipped file but a POSIX tar archive file. Which means it was not zipped at all but instead it was compressed using tar. Perhaps it was simply renamed afterwards.

So, try to extract the file using the following command:

- `tar xf MyFile.tar.gz`
- `tar xvf MyFile.tar.gz`
- `tar zxvf ies4linux-latest.tar.gz`

More detail information about install IE browser in Linux VM, please check this link:

[InstallingInternetExplorer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingInternetExplorer)

Besides, by using the above method, it just installs the old version of IE browser. To use the latest version IE browser, I think the best workaround is to install any Windows OS using a virtual machine. Than user can try to access that Windows OS from Linux OS and try to run their tests with IE browser. You could download the Windows Virtual Machine from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/), for Free for 90 days.

Comment: Hi Zhi Lv,I tried the above commands but still I am getting the same error

Comment: Try to use the `file` command to check the file type, more detail information, please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744023/how-to-extract-filename-tar-gz-file). Besides, I suggest you could try to download the Windows Virtual Machine and use it to using IE browser.